# Taking JSON information in another page on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

So Ive check quite a lot of examples and quite a lot of tutorials but it is definitely not working out for me for some unknown reason.

Ive already checked [Get JSON data from another page via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022800/get-json-data-from-another-page-via-javascript) and it didnt work out for me.

So what I want to do is take some information from MySQL and use it on a Jscript function I am using on another .php, this means taking information retrieved from mysql (connect.php) to another file (test.php), but although the information is correctly retrieved from connect.php it is not moving to the other file.

These are my files.

connect.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('dbexample') or die (mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lugares") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$arr = array();
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($data)) {
   $arr[] = array('latt' => $obj->latt,
               'lng' => $obj->long,
               'nombre' => $obj->nombre,
               'direccion' => $obj->direccion,
    );
 }
 echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
 ?>
```

test.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"connect.php",
            async: true,
            success: function(datos){
                var dataJson = eval(datos);

                for(var i in dataJson){
                    alert(dataJson[i].latt + " _ " + dataJson[i].lng + " _ " + dataJson[i].nombre);
                }

            },
            error: function (obj, error, objError){
                //avisar que ocurrió un error
            }
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Super freak</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I modified my script on test.php but something doesn't feel right; I'm losing it here :(

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"connect.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: true,
            success: function(datos){
                var dataJson = $.parseJSON(datos);

                $.each(dataJson, function(){
                    alert(dataJson.latt + "_"+ dataJson.lng);
                }

            },
            error: function (obj, error, objError){
                //avisar que ocurrió un error
            }
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the jQuery '$', don't forget to include jQuery to your page!

Comment: What error do you have ? You should firstly use Datatype: 'json' in your Ajax call.

Comment: Yep, thank you Ive corrected and added the JQuery library. And I added the datatype Json now :( still not displaying any alert or anything.

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues

1. your return type looks like json encoded in connect.php so add `dataType: JSON` in `$.ajax`
2. in test.php your success data should be json decoded to Jquery so you can use `$.parseJson(data)`.

   please refer this [example]: (http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-read-and-parse-json-using-jquery.html)

Comment: modified everything to no luck :/ ... I edited my first post to the considerations you specified. Still no alerts. Thanks!

Comment: i will see if i can come with an example

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `alert(dataJson[i].latt` to `alert(dataJson[i].users.latt`

I may be wrong on this, but it looks like you never get inside the users item that you hardcoded into the response.

Answer (score 0):

i see the problem
$.ajax is jquery element so
first include jquery.js file, then add document.ready inside this use $.ajax

the below example worked for me
this is your test.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  //start ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    //force to handle it as text
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {

      //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function
      //and pass downloaded data
      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
      //now json variable contains data in json format
      alert(jsonData.firstName);//access first array
      alert(jsonData.series[0]);//access second array elements

    }
  });



});
```

your connect.php should return json encoded array:

`$php_array = array('firstName'=>'Walter','lastName'=>'White',                 'series'=>array('episode1','episode2'));`

`echo json_encode($php_array);`

Comment: thing is, im taking the files from connect.php so I didnt I should call it somewhere and it is a JSON with many many rows not just one.

Comment: you can just add a loop and use what ever data you need to use. the code above was an example to parse your json response. check this out (http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery)